# Occasional error: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\user', error code 0x54b

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I have a query that will impersonate as a specific domain user to send email with attachment. This impersonation is required as it needs to read a file at some other server to be able to attach the file to the email.

The query is as follows

```
EXECUTE AS login='domain\user' -- To impersonate
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'profile_name',
    @recipients = @recipient,
    @copy_recipients = @cc,
    @blind_copy_recipients = @bcc,
    @subject = @subj,
    @body = @mail_body,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @from_address = 'email@address.com',
    @file_attachments = @files;
REVERT
```

Sometimes I get error when running the query with error message as:

```
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\user', error code 0x54b.
```

The weird thing is that, if I execute this query multiple times, it will work and it will send out the email.

What could possibly be wrong?

SQL Server version: 11.0.2100

Comment: Try to give sysadmin privilege to this domain user and execute the query.

Comment: Check here, may be it's your case: https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Troubleshooting/KB/KB00604

Comment: That error indicates that the specified domain does not exist. I would check that you are not having communications issues with your domain controllers. Check the system event log locally, and work with your domain admins to check the DCs for errors.

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly advise against using sysadmin privileges to simply send an email... have you ever hear of the principle of least privilege!? This wouldn't solve your problem, just provide a work around! Similarly, you would be enabling the login to drop databases, change passwords, and create all sorts of chaos!

Have you checked the SQL error logs, or the event logs. It may also be a good idea to check the logs on your DC, to see if there is any information there.

Are you having any problems with the account that the agent job is being execute as? Presumably this has the appropriate permissions for what you are asking? when you are executing the script you are executing it under your context, not the context of the agent. This is likely why it works for you all the time.

Without any additional information, preferably from your logs, it's difficult to help any better than this